# how to clone Drupal website from Acquia cloud to localhost using Git

Tags: git, drupal, cloud, clone, acquia

I am trying to Clone a website from Acquia Cloud to my localhost using Git.

I have entered this command

```
git clone URL
```

it returns

```
cloning into 'name'..
permission denied  (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 2):

Like it says in the documentation https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/ssh/enable :

> If you use Git to manage your Drupal code, you must enable SSH to access your server.

Have you enabled SSH on your server? Also, don't forget to add your public key otherwise cloning will not work : https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/ssh/enable/add-key